# Show description or comments for variables in FastAPI autodocs (Swagger UI)

Tags: swagger-ui, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

I'm making a function and class for it with `POST` method.

Since I use FastAPI, it automatically generates API docs (using OpenAPI specification and Swagger UI), where I can see the function's description or example data there.

My class and function are like below:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional, List


@app.post("/user/item")
def func1(args1: User, args2: Item):
    ...


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    state: List[str]

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "name": "Mike",
                "state": ["Texas", "Arizona"]
            }
        }


    class Item(BaseModel):
        _id: int = Field(..., example=3, description="item id")
```

Through `schema_extra` and `example` attribute in `Field`, I can see the example value in `Request body` of function description.

It shows like

```
{
   "args1": {
        "name": "Mike",
        "state": ["Texas", "Arizona"]     # state user visits. <-- I'd like to add this here or in other place.
    },
    "args2: {
        "_id": 3   <-- Here I can't description 'item id'
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to add description or comments to `example value`, like # state user visits above.

I've tried to add `description` attribute of `pydantic Field`, but I think it shows only for parameters of get method.

Is there any way to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass "comments" inside the actual `JSON` payload that will be sent to the server. Thus, such an approach wouldn't work. The way to add `description` to the fields is as shown below. Users/you can see the descriptions/comments, as well as the examples provided, by expanding the corresponding JSON schema of a Pydantic model (e.g., "User") under "Schemas" (at the bottom of the page) when visting OpenAPI at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, for instance. Or, by clicking on "Schema", next to "Example Value", above the example given in the "Request Body".

```python
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., description="Add user name")
    state: List[str]  = Field(..., description="State user visits")

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "name": "Mike",
                "state": ["Texas", "Arizona"]
            }
        }
```

Alternatively, you could use `Body` field in your endpoint, allowing you to add a description that is shown under the example in the "Request body". As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#technical-details):

> But when you use `example` or `examples` with any of the other utilities
> (`Query()`, `Body()`, etc.) those examples are not added to the JSON
> Schema that describes that data (not even to OpenAPI's own version of
> JSON Schema), they are added directly to the path operation
> declaration in OpenAPI (outside the parts of OpenAPI that use JSON
> Schema).

You could add multiple examples (with their associated descriptions), as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#body-with-multiple-examples). Example below:

```python
@app.post("/user/item")
async def update_item(
    user: User = Body(
        ...,
        examples={
            "normal": {
                "summary": "A normal example",
                "description": "**name**: Add user name.  **state**: State user vistis. ",
                "value": {
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "state": ["Texas", "Arizona"]
                },
            }
        }
    ),
):
    return {"user": user}
```