# In FastAPI framework, how do one add a description to a request body?

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

```py
@app.post("/items")
async def create_item(item: Item = Body(description="new")):
    return {"item": item.dict()}
```

I passed the `description` parameter to the request method, however the description is still missing from the interactive API docs.

I am expecting a description in the doc like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you restarting you application after you made those changes?

Comment: Just tried it out. Seems like the swagger version with fastapi has a different layout than what you're posting. Maybe add the comments to the `description` argument on `.post`. i.e. `@app.post("/items", description="new")`

Comment: @flakes-- If you put decription within decorateor as a parameter, it basically adds a description to the endpoint as a whole, but I need an individual description for the requestbody.

Comment: @PedroRocha-- yes.

Comment: If you put a docstring on the model class it will at least show up in the description of the schemas components entry, but yeah not ideal.

Comment: Maybe raise this as a bug on the fastapi github page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show description or comments for variables in FastAPI autodocs (Swagger UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027304/show-description-or-comments-for-variables-in-fastapi-autodocs-swagger-ui)

Comment: @Chris I want an description for the requested body as a whole not for individual