# FastAPI - multiple examples for Body in Response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I need to create multiple examples for the Response Body, to display it in API documentation http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs.
I found an example for the Request Body in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#openapi-examples-in-the-docs-ui) (there is drop-down list of: "A normal example", "An example with converted data", etc.), but I require the same approach for the Response Body.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    value: str
    model_config = {
        "json_schema_extra": {
            "examples": [
                {"value": "A normal example"},  # working
                {"value": "An example with converted data"},  # NOT WORKING
                {"value": "Invalid data ..."},  # NOT WORKING
            ]
        }
    }


@app.get(path="/")
def get1() -> Item:
    return Item(value="a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71029291/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the `response` parameter in the decorator method.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    message: str

get1_responses = {
    200: {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "examples": {
                    "Normal": {"value": {"message": "A normal example"}},
                    "Converted": {"value": {"message": "An example with converted data"}},
                }
            }
        },
    },
    400 : {
        "description": "Bad request",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "example": {"message": "Invalid data ..."}
            }
        },
    }
}


@app.get(path="/", responses=get1_responses)
def get1() -> Item:
    return Item(message="a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

The swagger UI
[image]

Comment: The example is working, but I was confused because 'key="value"' is used both in the 'Item' class and in 'get1_responses', but they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have updated the input name to make it less confusing and updated the examples. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The same as in answer before, but more accurate data types

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    value: str


get1_responses = {
    200: {
        "description": "Success",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "examples": {
                    "Normal": {
                        "value": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "value": "A normal example",
                        }
                    },
                    "Converted": {
                        "value": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "value": "An example with converted data",
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        },
    },
    400: {
        "description": "Bad request",
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "example": {"value": "Invalid data ..."}
            }
        },
    }
}


@app.get(path="/", responses=get1_responses)
def get1() -> Item:
    return Item(value="a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```